# Axios Token issue?

Tags: redux, token, axios

I have a Sign Up/Sign in/Sign Out issue. I am creating a React/Redux project, and am using Axios for my GET & POST requests. I am newer to Axios and have read through the documentation to no avail.

Here is the issue. 
 1. I can successfully create a user with Sign Up in a sign up form.
 2. I can make a Post request(a couple of strings) with a basic Redux form. 
 3. The user and post both are persisting in MongoDB, and I am getting  token back. 
 4. When I log out of that new user, and sign back in with that new user, I am able to sign in, but my post shows up as a 401. Intuition and research tell me that this is an issue with the token, but then again, I'm not sure why I'm able to sign in with the newly created user, but not able to make another post. Any help would be greatly appreciate. Here are my Axios methods:

```
var config = {
   headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') }
}

export function signinUser({ email, password }){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, {email, password})
            .then(response => {

                dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                browserHistory.push('/newitem');

         })
      .catch(response =>  dispatch(authError("There was a something wrong with your request.")));
    }
}

export function signoutUser(){
   localStorage.removeItem('token'); 
   return {type: UNAUTH_USER};
}

export function signupUser({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    // Submit email/password to the server
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signup`, { email, password })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});

          //update the token
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
          browserHistory.push('/newitem');
      })
      .catch(response => dispatch(authError(response.data.error)));
  }
}


export function createPost(props) {
  return function(dispatch){
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/newitem`, { props }, config )
    .then(request => {
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_POSTS,
          payload: request
        })
      browserHistory.push('/items');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your authentication middleware/controller so we can see if the auth issue is on your backend?

Comment: Is it possible that you are not updating the `config` variable? Once you assign it to a token, you don't seem to be changing anymore. In `createPost`, before calling `axios.post` try writing `var config = {
   headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') }
}`again.